# Subclassing model causes changes to the database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a simple department model:

```
public class Department
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int LeagueID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual League League { get; set; }
}
```

which is added in my ApplicationDbContext:

```
public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
```

I've subclassed department for use in a viewmodel, just to add a count of members:

```
    public class DepartmentWithCount : Department
    {
        public DepartmentWithCount(Department d)
        {
            this.ID = d.ID;
            this.LeagueID = d.LeagueID;
            this.Name = d.Name;
        }
        public int MemberCount { get; set; }
    }
```

Even though I've made no changes to IdentityModels, on update-database it has changed the database and added a MemberCount and Discriminator field. I understand why this would be the case if I'd referenced DepartmentWithCount in IdentityModels, but I don't understand why it would in this situation.

Is there any way for me to subclass Department without these effects?

Answer (score -1):

Use the [NotMapped] attribute before the subclass